# Cannot establish tunnel to Elasticsearch deployed via Google's Cloud Launcher

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm attempting to establish a tunnel to the elastic stack I setup with the google launcher. I am however running into this issue. I tried updated putty/plink. Resetting the .ssh it generates. Windows platform. Anyone know how to resolve?

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-L9200:localhost:9200 --project=xxxxx --zone=us-central1-f elasticsearch-1-elastic-vm-0

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud- 
sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe] exited with return code [1].
```

plink: unknown option "-L9200:localhost:9200"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space after '-L' in your command and the flag should be passed using double quotes as can be seen in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag).

> gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-L 9200:localhost:9200" --project=xxxxx
>   --zone=us-central1-f elasticsearch-1-elastic-vm-0

Comment: I'm running the command that they were directing me to do even if I space it out like that is fails. I solved it by doing there tunneling documentation. So doesn't surprise me that more information that doesn't match what needs to happen.

i followed this: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce